# MVC3 - How to check if user clicked on the link you sent through e-mail in .net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm running an e-commerce website and I send my customers regular newsletters.
I'm using nopcommerce v2.40.
I just see who all are subscribed. I want to develop a detailed newsletter management system, something like MailChimp.
I want a report on how many users actually clicked on the link that I sent them via e-mail.
Can anyone tell me how to do that??
This is a pretty generalized question but I'm new at this and I have no idea how to do it.

Thank you !

Comment: Sure, add some sort of a hash that is associated with the email address and verify it through the QueryString

Comment: u mean add some query-string at the end of the promotional link and everytime its clicked, increment the counter?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Maybe you can store the hashes and associate them with a particular email address as well. You get the idea.

Comment: oh right.. tat can be done.. but associating a unique string with a particular e-mail id wud be tedious coz i have almost 5-6k subscribers.. any other way i can check which user clicked??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing quite simply with Google Analytics.

Here are some links worth looking at.

[Google Analytics Email Tracking](http://www.tweaky.com/blog/google-analytics-email-tracking-reports/)

[Setting up campaign tracking in Google Analytics](http://www.smartinsights.com/google-analytics/google-analytics-campaign-tracking/marketing-campaigns-tracking/)

Comment: I checked this but im not sure how to use it. I just have to add the required fields in the url and tats done??? and everything else will be taken care by google analytics? is it so? or r there any steps to be followed in google analytics?

Comment: Yes that's right, there is URL builder to help you form the URL's correctly https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en After that Google will track the campaign's.  These can be found in Google Analytics under Traffic sources > Campaigns

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

in your email newsletter add params you need to collect.

Example

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/ClickController/Index?redirect=page-you-want-to-display-after-click&email=email&name=john">click to view</a>
```

Everytime someone would click on the above link, they would be taken to your default controller that collects clicks and other parameters you want. You would then save that data and redirect to an actual page you want them to see via "redirect" parameter provided in the url.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks !! That's pretty simple.